# Is a method return value stored anywhere when doing python if statement?

Tags: python

In the python interpreter when a method returns and it's not being stored to a variable it's being put into the `_` variable by default

```
In [10]: def foo(x):
   ....:     return x
   ....: 

In [11]: foo(1)
Out[11]: 1

In [12]: _
Out[12]: 1

In [13]: x = foo(2)

In [14]: _
Out[14]: 1

In [15]: x
Out[15]: 2
```

I was wondering if it also stores to another variable when doing a comparison statement?  Something like this

```
In [16]: if foo(2):
   ....:     print <the returned value from foo>
   ....:     
2
```

Obviously this doesn't work and I have to do something like this

```
In [17]: returned_value_from_foo = foo(2)

In [18]: if returned_value_from_foo:
   ....:     print returned_value_from_foo
   ....:   
2
```

Comment: _ is a convenience for interactive coding. You shouldn't be using it in real code except as a dummy variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is **no**.

The use of `_` in the interpreter is just a convenience for doing interactive work. I use it when I'm using my Python environment as a calculator, for example. It's not meant to be used as a real variable and as far as I know this behavior doesn't even exist outside of the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good time to highlight the difference between a statement and an expression.  Expressions always return some value (which may be `None`) and are made up of things like arithmetic expressions, function calls, list comprehensions, etc.

Statements on the other hand do not necessarily return a value (most do not). Things like `if` and `while`, `for`, `import`, and variable assignment are examples of statements and do not return any value in python.

Every expression can also stand alone as a statement, but the reverse is not true.

In the case of `if`, there is also a conditional *expression* form, but it looks a little different:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> y = 20 if x == 10 else 5
>>> y
20
>>> x = 15
>>> y = 20 if x == 10 else 5
>>> y
5
```